# Why isn't the value of list passed in a function getting updated?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

```
def mystery(l):
  l = l[0:5] #<-problem here
  return()

list1 = [44,71,12,8,23,17,16]
mystery(list1)
```

When I print list1, the answer is [44,71,12,8,17,16]. Why didn't list1 get updated in line l=l[0:5], since lists are mutable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`l` is a local variable; assigning to a name never alters the object it used to refer to. If you want to truncate the list referred to by `l`, you need to use something like

```
l[:] = l[0:5]  # Replace the contents of the list with just the first 5
```

or more simply

```
del l[5:]  # Remove all but the first 5 elements
```